# mysql: select all fields starting with 2012-02*

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

How can i select all fields in mysql starting with "2012-02"?

What i've tried:

```
mysql> SELECT title,id FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date = '2012-02-13 21:35:00';
+-------------------------------------------------+----+
| title                                           | id |
+-------------------------------------------------+----+
| test title                                      |  7 |
+-------------------------------------------------+----+


mysql> SELECT title,id FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date='2012-02%';
Empty set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '2012-02%' for column 'date' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '2012-02%' for column 'date' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can't use wilcards in equality tests. your second query should be `... AND date LIKE '2012-02%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, dates should be treated as dates, not as strings. This query should return all rows for February 2012 and it should outperform `LIKE %` queries:

```
SELECT title, id
FROM dle_post
WHERE approve = 1 
AND date >= '2012-02-01' 
AND date <  '2012-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: Or `date BETWEEN 20120201 AND 20120229`.

Comment: Actually `date BETWEEN 20120201 AND 20120229235959`.

Comment: Ah, `datetime`, not `date`. So also `DATE(date) BETWEEN 20120201 AND 20120229`.

Comment: Yes that will work. The flip side: `DATE()` is a function; using it in a where clause means MySQL has to go through each `date` and calculate `DATE(date)` in order to do a comparison. If you have 100,000 rows this becomes terribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
SELECT title,id FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date LIKE '2012-02%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like operator to check for values like these

```
SELECT title,id FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date LIKE '2012-02%';
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
date LIKE '2012-02%'
```

instead of

```
date='2012-02%'
```

You might also probably have to cast the date to string with with DATE_FORMAT(date,format)

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format